# Loss in multi-class classification

Tags: classification, loss-function, multiclass-classification

I have a multi-class classification task. One of the standard approach in choosing loss function is to use a CrossEntropyLoss. It is a good option when classes are standonlone and not similar to each other.

What if some classes are more similar?

For example, if I have 10 classes, from `0` to `9` and classes with nearby numbers are closer to each other, i.e `4` and `6` are closer to `5` than `0` and `9`, etc.

How can I modify CrossEntropyLoss to reflect this fact? Or maybe already exists such loss function?

Comment: What's the problem when some classes are more similar? I think you need to clarify that first. In any case, a weighted cross entropy could be the thing you are searching for.

Comment: @Alessandro because CE can't consider the fact that classes are ordinal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in loss function for what you want - I had the same issue a few years back and I found a [custom loss function](https://github.com/JHart96/keras_ordinal_categorical_crossentropy) for this purpose. It is called **Ordinal Categorical Classification** problem. I have not checked this in a while now but I believe it is still not implemented in Keras.

You can also check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140061/how-to-set-up-neural-network-to-output-ordinal-data) cross-validated question and the references given in the answers.

Comment: Have you encountered ordinal function with two-side ranking? For example, ordinal classes are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and $P_{arg\_max} = 2$, then it should be $P(0) < P(1) < P(2) > P(3) > P(4)$.

Comment: No, but I don't really understand it. How is P(3) related to P(1) and P(0)?

Comment: Ranking with property (0)<(1)<(2) and (2)>(3)>(4) and their sum (from $P_0$ to $P_4$) equals to zero.